# mapreduce fails with message "The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large."

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am running a mapreduce job over 50 million User records.

For each user I read two other Datastore entities and then stream stats for each player to bigquery.

My first dry run (with streaming to bigquery disabled) failed with the following stacktrace.

/_ah/pipeline/handleTask
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.pipeline.impl.backend.AppEngineBackEnd.tryFiveTimes(AppEngineBackEnd.java:196)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.pipeline.impl.backend.AppEngineBackEnd.saveWithJobStateCheck(AppEngineBackEnd.java:236)

I have googled this error and the only thing I find is related to that the Mapper is too big to be serialized but our Mapper has no data at all.

```
/**  
 *  Adds stats for a player via streaming api.
 */
public class PlayerStatsMapper extends Mapper<Entity, Void, Void> {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PlayerStatsMapper.class.getName());

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String dataset;
private String table;

private transient GbqUtils gbq;

public PlayerStatsMapper(String dataset, String table) {
    gbq = Davinci.getComponent(GbqUtils.class);

    this.dataset = dataset;
    this.table = table;
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    log.info("IOC reinitating due to deserialization.");
    gbq = Davinci.getComponent(GbqUtils.class);
}

@Override
public void beginShard() {
}

@Override
public void endShard() {
}

@Override
public void map(Entity value) {
    if (!value.getKind().equals("User")) {
        log.severe("Expected a User but got a " + value.getKind());
        return;
    }

    User user = new User(1, value);

    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();
    List<PlayerStats> playerStats = readPlayerStats(user.getUserId());
    addRankings(user.getUserId(), playerStats);

    for (PlayerStats ps : playerStats) {
        rows.add(ps.asMap());
    }

//      if (rows.size() > 0)
//          gbq.insert(dataset, table, rows);
}


    .... private methods only

}
```

The maprecuce job is started with this code

```
    MapReduceSettings settings = new MapReduceSettings().setWorkerQueueName("mrworker");
    settings.setBucketName(gae.getAppName() + "-playerstats");

    // @formatter:off  <I, K, V, O, R>
    MapReduceSpecification<Entity, Void, Void, Void, Void> spec = 
            MapReduceSpecification.of("Enque player stats", 
                    new DatastoreInput("User", shardCountMappers),
                    new PlayerStatsMapper(dataset, "playerstats"),          
                    Marshallers.getVoidMarshaller(),
                    Marshallers.getVoidMarshaller(), 
                    NoReducer.<Void, Void, Void> create(), 
                    NoOutput.<Void, Void> create(1));
    // @formatter:on
    String jobId = MapReduceJob.start(spec, settings);
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the exception you mentioned above? Also at what point does the Job fail if you look at it's status in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this by backing to appengine-mapreduce-0.2.jar which was the one we had used before. The one used above was appengine-mapreduce-0.5.jar which actually turned out not to work for us.

When backing to 0.2 the console _ah/pipiline/list started to work again as well!

Anyone else that have encountered similar problem with 0.5?